# Post to facebook-wall

Tags: php, facebook

I suppose this question is asked here many times before, but I couldn't find any solution that works for me.

It is a very common thing, you see all over the internet. A user can add a piece of clothing to my website with some pictures. After he has done so, I want to give him the opportunity to share it on his facebook-wall with a picture, a description and link to my site.

Can anybody help me on my way, because I can't find a good starting point.

Comment: How about the official documentation? Let's say [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) or [Send Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/)?

Comment: Yes I'm using php. I checked the official documentation, first thing I did. It isn't really the send of like button I need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a `Post object` over to the `Users.stream` connection. For instance, take a look at the following tool to play around with the API call. Click "Get Access Token" and grant under "Extended Permissions" the "publish_stream" call. You can try an simple POST to your wall by clicking "Add a field", and then add a field with Name 'message' with the value set your message.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=me%2Ffeed

This is the documents describes the structure of the Post object. It looks like you want to take a look at the 'picture' field and also the 'link' field.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/